# Array with variable change after time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a array with variables and these variables should change themselves after a given time. Here is my code:

```
var cookieArray =  new Array(window.setInterval(myCallback, 2000));

function myCallback() {
    cookie1  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie2  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie3  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie4  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie5  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie6  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie7  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie8  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie9  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    cookie10 =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were creating an array, but not initializing it.
To initialize an array, you should use `arrayName[0]=value` in your case.

```js
 var cookieArray =[];
 
window.setInterval(myCallback, 2000);

function myCallback() {
        cookieArray[0]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
        cookieArray[1]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);

        console.log(cookieArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
var cookieArray=(new Array(10)).fill(0);//create a new Array with 0s

setInterval(function(){
   //refill array every 2seconds
   cookieArray=cookieArray.map(()=>Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0));
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you took is OK but contains a lot of programming errors.
First of all, to declare you array you must do the following :

```
var cookieArray = new Array(10);
```

Which means the `cookieArray`will have 10 elements. To access each one of its elements, you can use `cookieArray[i]` where `i` refers to the `i + 1` th element of the array.

In the end, I would do :

```
var cookieArray = new Array(10);

setInterval(function() {
    for(int i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
         cookieArray[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
    }
}, 2000);
```

here, `setInterval` is the same as `window.setInterval`.